# Ubuntu became unreliable on my laptop. Is it possible to find the root cause?

Tags: drivers, xorg, hardware, wayland

I have been using an Asus X556UQ since 2017.  The laptop has a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu as a primary OS (the current version is 22.04). Unfortunately, my Ubuntu has become unreliable. I am experiencing random delays in GUI response, and, worse, periodical crashes of GUI sessions with Gnome (X11 and Wayland), and KDE. I saved a lot of logs after crashes, but I couldn't figure out the problem. NetworkManager often stops after a crash. Sometimes I lose the mouse and keyboard. There is one example of a recent incident that is very typical.
 I needed to make an urgent online transaction. After I entered the URL, Firefox was killed by the OOM killer. There were only a few applications open: Nautilus, a terminal window, a text editor with a few small files, and Firefox with about 30 tabs. I also thought oomd was disabled. Anyway, Firefox was killed. I restarted the browser and started the transaction. I was on the very last page when GNOME disappeared. Instead of a GUI, I saw a dark screen with GPM mouse pointer. I switched to a virtual terminal and launched "top".  X11 was not there anymore. I went to the login screen. I was able to get the screen, but the laptop froze, no mouse. no keyboard, no network.  I could only do a forced shutdown.
 I attached two days' info from syslog. https://pastebin.com/qjgLCVJK  The crash happened on Oct 13.
I have several questions about this incident. The main question is how to research a GUI session disappearing. (I already mentioned that this  happened with GNOME on X11 and Wayland, and KDE  on X11.) I also have questions about the OOM killer, but that's a different topic, and I wouldn't mix them up.
My questions are:

- it could be a random hardware problem. Windows 10 seems to work well though. Is there a way to explore problems like this?
- Could there be a problem with the video driver? The laptop has dual video, integrated Intel and NVIDIA GPU. I only use Intel. Prime is set to Intel. This should stop NVIDIA.
  My Ubuntu used to run pretty stable with the Intel card. Have there been any changes to the Intel driver?
- Could this be due to low memory? Or memory management problems? 30 Firefox tabs on Windows don't even slow down the system. However, in my latest case, oomd killed FF with 30 tabs when two more windows were opened.

Adding information about my laptop. The laptop has 8GB of RAM. I use 8GB swapfile to make hibernation working. I printed below the output of swapon command

```
swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size        Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        8388604     552600  -2
```

I noticed in the swapon output, that the priority is -2, when according to the manual the priority range should be
-1 and 32767. What does "-2" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need swap space! The failures you describe are typical of a system without swap.

One uses swap space to control what happens when programs allocate all the real memory, and want more. After all releasable cache (some cached blocks are "in use", and cannot be freed) has been released, the system enters the Out-Of-Memory state. In the Out-Of-Memory condition, with swap, some task's memory is written to disk, freed for reuse, and later  returned to memory (swapped in) when the task runs. Without swap, the system may freeze,  the dreaded OOM-Killer (a pseudo process, hard-coded in the kernel) runs, and picks a process to KILL, in order to free memory. The OOM-Killer is known for inconvenient choices.

System hibernation requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap area.

Read `man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab`.

Comment: I apologize for not saying this initially. My laptop has 8GB of RAM. I use 8GB swapfile to make hibernation working

Comment: there are my settings  `swapon -s`
`Filename    Type  Size  Used Priority`
`/swapfile                               file  8388604  552600 -2``

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: I have updated the question with one finding